# Dual monitor Unity launcher opening on wrong monitor

Tags: unity, nvidia, 11.04, multiple-monitors, launcher

Is this a specific unity configuration or a dual monitor configuration problems ?

*In NVIDIA X Server Settings. Make this the primary display for the X screen, is my choice the middle display. But the launcher is on the left display.*

Comment: This sound like a bug, consider reporting it on launchpad. But since unity is still in alpha versions, you should be not surprised it works incorrectly. If I were you I would give it more time and see whether they'll fix it.

Comment: Can you specify in the question what version of ubuntu you're using?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narwhal Alpha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently Unity sits itself down at 0,0. Supporting right monitor as primary is simply not implemented yet. It will be by release.

Comment: Good news. I have the same issue with dual monitor extended on the left of my notebook.

Comment: Ok, the release has happened. How come the launcher still doesn't understand it's supposed to be on the left screen?

Comment: I have this problem in 11.10 too.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell this has been fixed for nVidia binary driver in the Natty release.

For other graphics drivers there may be still issues, such as [Bug 742544](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/742544).

Screenshots of my setup:

[image]

[image: desktop]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the cleanest way to set my primary monitor (the monitor launcher is displayed on) is with /etc/X11/xorg.conf

The important changes I have made are:

```
Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
Option "TwinViewOrientation" "RightOf"
```

- **TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder**

  - set's the primary monitor that Unity will display the launcher on.
- **TwinViewOrientation**

  - set's the monitors place automatically without having to specify the resolution. (This is handy for me because of the different monitors I connect to (and the lack of monitor at times)).

My complete /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL SE198WFP"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400M GS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select, DFP: nvidia-auto-select"
    Option         "TwinViewOrientation" "RightOf"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```