# Setting Primary Monitor for Launcher on Natty 11.04

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have a dual monitor setup. It runs ATI drivers on Natty 11.04 as stated in title.

I've got it to run dual monitors but i can't get my primary monitor to be set for the left monitor. Any ideas on how i could do this?

There's a thread regarding this topic but it's regarding *Nvidia* drivers:

- [Dual monitor Unity launcher opening on wrong monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17074/dual-monitor-unity-launcher-opening-on-wrong-monitor)
- [How to Configure Launcher Placement in Multi-monitor Setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42353/move-left-launcher-to-another-monitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the primary monitor only requires selecting the "Make Default" button in the "monitor settings".

This will switch which monitor the unity bar is placed.